# Remove unused IntelliJ IDEA features?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

Is there any possibility to remove unused features from IntelliJ IDEA 14?

Purpose:

- better performance
- ease of use

Some examples for unused features:

- File > New Project... - Griffon, Flash
- File > Settings... > Editor > Code Style - ActionScript, CoffeeScript, Gherkin
- Tools > Capture Memory Snapshot

Answer (score 20):

Choose Menu **File \ Settings...** or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>. Choose **Plugins**, disable unnecessary plugin:

[image]

Then press **Apply**, **OK**, restart IntelliJ IDEA to feeling the difference. That help decrement IntelliJ IDEA's start up time, and increment performance (like suggest code , operation faster etc.)

Need speed up more? you see: http://hamletdarcy.blogspot.com/2008/02/10-tips-to-increase-intellij-idea.html

Reference: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/enabling-and-disabling-plugins.html

Answer (score 8):

As far as I know you can only do this by disabling built-in plugins in `Settings` > `Plugins`

Comment: A good tip is to untick all the plugins when you install IntelliJ, and only apply the ones you actually need. This will speed up loading times, reduce weird menu options, etc.

Answer (score 2):

There were 2 purposes in the question: performance & usability.

The first one already has some good answers.

Regarding the usability, it can be improved in **IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.3**. To achieve this, go to:

**File** > **Settings...** > **Appearance & Behavior** > **Menus and Toolbars** and remove the unused features. You can also add horizontal lines as separators in menus or change the items order.

[image]

I don't know if the performance is affected by this change.